# How can I get all words that contain a particular letter from an array?

Tags: javascript

How to find elements of an array that contain the letter `a`, and insert them into a temporary array?

```js
const fruits = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'lemons', 'limes'];

function letterA (fruits){
    const tempArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if (fruits.includes('a'))  {
           fruits.push(tempArray[i]);
        } 
        if (tempArray.length) {
            return tempArray;
        } else {
            console.log ("No elements with character 'a' found");
        }
    }
} 

letterA(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fix of your code using `for` loop. The `if` statement must check if `fruits[i]` includes `'a'`, then push to `tempArray` if true. Then checks if the `tempArray` has any elements and if so, it returns the `tempArray`. If not, it returns the string `"No elements with character 'a' found"`.

```js
const fruits = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'lemons', 'limes'];

function letterA (fruits){
    const tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if (fruits[i].includes('a'))  {
           tempArray.push(fruits[i]);
        } 
    }
    if (tempArray.length) {
        return tempArray;
    } else {
        return "No elements with character 'a' found";
    }
} 

let result = letterA(fruits);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` method:

```js
const fruits = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'lemons', 'limes'];
const filtered = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.includes('a'))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer… But because I am new in JS I must do a task with For loop and else statement if I don’t have a letter a...  I only can find advanced answers...

Comment: @Koala I made a new answer using for loop

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution with for - of loop:

```
  const fruits = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'lemons', 'limes'];
  const result = [];
  for (const item of fruits) {
    if(item.includes('a')){
     result.push(item);
   }
 }

console.log(result)
```